# Scripting - Remove Unused References

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

The current application Im working on has over 300 lightweight projects which then are then built into a single application (with a lot of dlls).

Ive started to notice a lot of the projects have a number of unused references which are slowly being removed using the "Unused References..." button in Visual Studio on each project.

Is there any way I could script this activity over every project or a tool I could use? I dont want to have to go through the projects individually.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

300 DLLs for a project, personaly I think is a big number. If I was you I would write a custom MS Build Task to IL Merge DLLs together to speed up overall working.

MS Build Task:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171466.aspx
```

IL Merge:

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx
```

Comment: Why use IL merge in this situation?

Comment: I agree its not ideal and is something we are addressing. The query was regarding the scripting of unused references though, any ideas?

Comment: To batch up couple of dlls together as one dll, so that visual studio can load less number of dlls